# Windows kernel conditional breakpoint not evaluating

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, windbg, breakpoints

I'm using the windows kernel debugger through visual studio 2013 and I'm trying to stop (break) in a function (`nt!KiSwapContext`) but only for a specific process (`0x920`).

The breakpoint works without a condition `bp nt!KiSwapContext`

I determined the Process ID for the current thread can be found with `dt dword poi(gs:[188h])+3B8h`

I've confirmed the following conditional works to see if I am on the right thread: `? poi(poi(gs:[188h])+3B8h)==0x920`

However, when I try to set the conditional breakpoint it always breaks no matter what I put in the if/else . So I am guessing it thinks the expression is invalid and is just ignoring it. I've confirmed that if I do enter an invalid expression it just accepts it without warning or error and always stops on the breakpoint.

The expression I am using is: `bp nt!KiSwapContext ".if (poi(poi(gs:[188h])+3B8h)==0x920) {} .else {gc}"`

I also tried using the `j` conditional syntax to no avail.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

[Edit] Oh, as a bonus, how can I do the conditional check with a dword instead of a qword on a 64 bit processor. `? poi(poi(gs:[188h])+3B8h)` returns a qword value. I know I can use `dd` to get the value, but I can't seem to figure out how to add that into the conditional. Something like `? dword(poi(gs:[188h])+3B8h)==0x920` or `? {dd poi(gs:[188h])+3B8h}==0x920`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

windbg allows you to set `process specific breakpoints  with /p`
you shouldn't be mucking with gs and fs registers

```
kd> bl

kd> !process 0 0 calc.exe
Failed to get VAD root
PROCESS 8113d528  SessionId: 0  Cid: 07a0    Peb: 7ffde000  ParentCid: 043c
    DirBase: 03d27000  ObjectTable: e15ba240  HandleCount:  28.
    Image: calc.exe

kd> bp /p 8113d528 nt!KiSwapContext "?? (char *)(@$proc->ImageFileName)"
kd> g
char * 0x8113d69c
 "calc.exe"
nt!KiSwapContext:
804db828 83ec10          sub     esp,10h
kd> g
char * 0x8113d69c
 "calc.exe"
nt!KiSwapContext:
804db828 83ec10          sub     esp,10h
```

use dwo() and qwo () as required to evaluate dword and qword

```
kd> ? qwo ( ffb9cda8 + 70)
Evaluate expression: -9142252815570161280 = 81203180`81203180
kd> ? dwo ( qwo ( ffb9cda8 + 70))
Evaluate expression: -4600296 = ffb9ce18

confirmation

kd> dd 81203180 l1
81203180  ffb9ce18
kd> dd ffb9cda8+70 l1
ffb9ce18  81203180
```

**Edit**

I cant access an x64 system atm so cant tell you what is the error in your expression
but in general you should avoid hardcoding unless it is absolutely necessary

in your case it is not necessary

windbg provides you pseudo registers to what you are hard coding

`$thread  to c++ Expression for CurrentThread * ie  (nt!_ETHREAD *)` .

so `$thread->Cid.UniqueProcess` is what you are evaluating with your gsexxxxx

with that in mind you can set a breakpoint like this

**bp nt!KiSwapContext " r? $t0 = @$thread->Cid.UniqueProcess ;.if( @$t0 != 0x740 ) {? @$t0;?? (char * )@$proc->ImageFileName ;gc }"**

this conditional will break only in calc.exe is the Current Process

```
kd> g
Evaluate expression: 404 = 00000194
char * 0x81105c84
 "csrss.exe"
XXXXXXXXXXX
Evaluate expression: 4 = 00000004
char * 0x8129196c
 "System"
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Evaluate expression: 1404 = 0000057c
char * 0x8114a4bc
 "vpcmap.exe"
Evaluate expression: 480 = 000001e0
char * 0x8112a98c
 "services.exe"
Evaluate expression: 492 = 000001ec
char * 0x811cc9ac
 "lsass.exe"
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
Evaluate expression: 1116 = 0000045c
char * 0xffaf9da4
 "explorer.exe"
Evaluate expression: 644 = 00000284
char * 0xffb74f14
 "svchost.exe"

nt!KiSwapContext: <---------------------------Conditional broke here
804db828 83ec10          sub     esp,10h

kd> ? @$t0;?? (char * )@$proc->ImageFileName
Evaluate expression: 1856 = 00000740
char * 0x8110e76c
 "calc.exe"
```

keep in mind evaluating conditions in a very hot path will make you endure unbearable pain  watching it crawl by

nt!kiSwapContext is called hundreds of  times in few seconds
and you will be seeing a very noticeable performance degradation in your 
Session

whenever possible use process specific or thread specific breakpoints 
do not evaluate conditions

no i don't use any cheat sheet ( google says there are few available ) i prefer manual or in some cases online msdn documentation

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been going through lots of documentation on the windows kernel debugger and am having real trouble finding info like this. You wouldn't happen to know of a good cheat sheet reference would you? And any thoughts on why it wouldn't accept my command? Like, is there a typo in there? Or do you expect just trying to find it using my processor number hack to be the problem?

Comment: Again, thank you so much. I actually just read through the entire section on MSDN about kernel debugging. The most important things I had needed to know anyways were all in what you gave me! I'll probably be referring back to your answer for a while until I get used to some of the variables and commands.

Comment: Also, in your new code, I think `@$t0 != 0x740` you might have meant to have that as `==`. And I now know that instead of putting the bp into the KiSwapContext, I should have just used "bu PROCESSNAME!*" (I think that is the syntax).

Comment: Sorry Processname!* Is not right  it is <module>!symbol  as to !=. It is opposite of ==. I dont prefer writing evaluation for cases where i want to break i discard what i dont want----  look at your blank {},. ,it consumes more time to evaluate two conditions insted of one  if foo == blah dothis else dothat is kinda longer than if foo != Woow exit

Comment: I think I just noticed what the problem was in my original question. I had "==" instead of "=" for equality. Darn MASM syntax :-)

Comment: No == shouldn't be confused with = firstone is comparison operator second one is assignment operator.

Comment: Hmm, both actually seem to do the same thing in MASM syntax. You can't do assignment directly in a statement, I think. You have to use the "e*" and "r" commands